# I cant access items more than a single image of my react app after hosting it on hostgator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, cpanel, shared-hosting

I was creating a website ([www.nycalco.com](http://www.nycalco.com))
I worked on localhost and kept pushing the code on Github. I deployed the app on firebase to access the outputs (https://nycal-co.web.app/)
Now after deploying the website on Hostgator, I can't access the files!
Please help!

Comment: The image you see is coming from a stylesheet at `./index.css` which is being loaded, though the stylesheet "chunks" generated by webpack from your react app aren't.  Basically none of the React code is being loaded at all and I can't tell you exactly why, but I can see in the HTML source that no javascript is being included.  It has something to do with the environment and the environment variables because `%PUBLIC_URL%` is being treated as a literal string rather than a placeholder and is not being replaced by the actual URL like it should.

Comment: perhaps this helps? https://community.netlify.com/t/cant-access-my-netlify-site-netlify-site-wont-load/11302/21 and https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2575